# Pass props to the JSX elements dynamically

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an x object

```
const x = {
   d: {D: 10},
   f: {F: 11},
   g: {G: 12}
}
```

I want to pass all values to a div tag,

```
<div D = {10} F = {11} G = {12}> </ div>
```

how do i make the shortest option?

Comment: any specific reason why you are using  `d: {D: 10}`  and not directly  `D: 10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to create an object out the nested keys and then pass it on to the div. You can make use of spread syntax with `Object.assign` to do that

```js
const x = {
   d: {D: 10},
   f: {F: 11},
   g: {G: 12}
}

console.log(Object.assign({}, ...Object.values(x)))
```

Based on the above code, you would do

```
<div {...Object.assign({}, ...Object.values(x))}> </ div>
```